# Acronis Backup 2009 cannot access Acronis Backup 2014 files

Tags: backup, compatibility

I have 2009 on one machine and 2014 on another. Made full backup with 2014 machine to external hard drive, that has other 2009 backups on it. Open external hard drive on 2009 machine. I can read all old backups taken with 2009 but when try to open backup from 2014 machine it tells me it is corrupt.Try to read it on 2014 machine and its fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally normal for just about every software package. :)

Advances are made over time, and data structures change to support new/changed features.

Newer versions are backwards-compatible because they know the old data structure (as well as the new), but the old software doesn't know how to handle the new data structure, so you'll need the new version on the computer you want to read the new data on.